# Nested Table With Iterable Bounds

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I have a set of data that looks vaguely like this:

```
data = {{{a,x1,y1,a},{a,x1,y1,a},{a,x1,y1,a},{a,x1,y1,a},{a,x1,y1,a}},
{{b,x2,y2,b},{b,x2,y2,b},{b,x2,y2,b}},
{{c,x3,y3,c},{c,x3,y3,c},{c,x3,y3,c},{c,x3,y3,c}}}
```

where the quantities I am interested in are the x and y values and the a, b, c are simply identifiers I don't need anymore.

I was attempting to extract those values and put them into a new set called positions that then looks like:

```
positions = {{{x1,y1},{x1,y1},{x1,y1},{x1,y1},{x1,y1}},
{{x2,y2},{x2,y2},{x2,y2}},
{{x3,y3},{x3,y3},{x3,y3},{x3,y3}}}
```

using a double table structure:

```
  positions = Table[{data[[1]][[i]][[2]], data[[1]][[i]][[3]]}, {j, 1, Length[data]}, {i, 1, Length[data[[j]]]}]
```

but it hasn't worked. I believe my problem is just where I have placed / how I have used the iterators. I was wondering if anyone could show me where I have gone wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `positions = data[[All, All, {2, 3}]]`, or by adjusting your code:

```
positions = Table[{data[[j]][[i]][[2]], data[[j]][[i]][[3]]},
              {j, 1, Length[data]}, {i, 1, Length[data[[j]]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

try [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
data[[All, All, {2, 3}]]
```

> {{{x1, y1}, {x1, y1}, {x1, y1}, {x1, y1}, {x1, y1}}, {{x2, y2}, {x2, 
>      y2}, {x2, y2}}, {{x3, y3}, {x3, y3}, {x3, y3}, {x3, y3}}}